# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test returning a p-value of 1

Tags: python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two datasets `data1` and `data2` with different sample sizes: over 50,000 and around 8,000, respectively. These data consist of positive integer values varying from 1 to 50.

(Due to the size of the data, I cannot upload the entire set. Instead, I upload the histogram of these datasets.)

[image]

(The histogram below shows the normalized version with `log` applied to `count`.)

[image]

My objective is to see whether there exists any statistically significant difference between the cumulative distributions of these two dataset values. Hence, I performed a 2-sample KS test via Python (using `ks_2samp` from `scipy.stats` package).

I have performed three tests in total with different null hypotheses:

- $H_0^1:\ \text{data1} \neq \text{data2}$
- $H_0^2:\ \text{data1} > \text{data2}$
- $H_0^3:\ \text{data1} < \text{data2}$

The resulting p-values are respectively: `3.448839769104661e-105`, `1.0`, and `1.5636837258561576e-105`. Not only the first and the last values are infinitesimal, but I find the second value the most absurd, as p-value being 1.0 seems infeasible.

Assuming that the execution in Python isn't incorrect, I'm wondering whether applying KS test in this case is inappropriate. However, I've done some research including Cross Validated, and it seems appropriate to do so.

Is KS test a correct test to achieve my objective? If not, what would be an adequate alternative? If so, what could I be doing wrong?

(I have asked a similar question in Stack Overflow: [ks_2samp returns p-value of 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561840/ks-2samp-returns-p-value-of-1-0). However, here I am asking for a mathematical explanation regarding KS test rather than a code fix.)

Comment: The KS test doesn't apply to discrete data--but with such large datasets, it doesn't matter.  These p-values are consistent with each other and there's nothing "absurd" about them.  As to your underlying problem: why not just examine a QQ plot of the two datasets? You will learn much more than any hypothesis test will show you.

Comment: Showing counts on log scale is a good idea (modulo some queasiness about showing bars on  log scale that start where? log of about 0.8??) but it doesn't "normalize" in any helpful sense. The display should adjust for the differing sample sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: Corrected my initial response after reading more about the one-sided KS-test.*

Note that your null hypotheses are written down wrongly, as these are about the underlying true distribution functions, not about the observed data. Also these look like the alternatives rather than the null hypothesis, which should be cdf1=cdf2 for all three tests.

The sample size is quite large, so the KS-test can clearly see that the two distributions are different. Furthermore it can clearly see that data1 tends to have larger values, so the first distribution seems to be stochastically larger than the second. Note that p-values are computed assuming the null hypothesis. The first p-value is essentially zero, meaning that it's crystal clear that the two underlying distributions are not equal. In fact it is crystal clear that the first distribution tends to produce larger values, as the third p-value shows, which is also essentially zero. The third p-value comes from looking at the negative differences between the two empirical cdfs (the first cdf will be uniformly *smaller* than the second if the first distribution is stochastically larger). The second p-value looks at positive differences. From looking at the histograms I'd think that indeed the first empirical cdf is uniformly smaller than the second one (i.e., the distribution stochastically larger), so there will be a maximum positive difference of zero, the smallest possible. This should give $p=1$ (there may be a tiny difference but that will still amount to 1.0 rounded as 1 is the leading digit so 1 minus something extremely small will be rounded to 1.0). So this is all correct.

Comment: The spirit of this is absolutely right but in practice the different sample sizes get in the way of interpreting the histograms.

Comment: A couple weeks ago I have conducted the similar test to different large samples and got somewhat less extreme p-values, but then my second and third p-values were not complementary at all. One turned out to be $6.245e-05$ and the other was $0.029$. Should they always add up to $1.0$?

Comment: Good question. I did some reading on the one-sided KS-test and realised that my initial answer (given out of the top of my head) was wrong (despite having picked up three positive votes already;-). I have updated it accordingly. Indeed they do not have to add to one, as one looks at positive and the other one at negative differences between the cdfs, which don't have to be symmetric.